# Query not rendering results when executed in SSRS 2008 R2 (BIDS 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

I have created a simple query which works in ssms but doesnt render the same result in Bids. The datasource is correct. See the query below with parameters created in Bids as well.

The reason i am using one table is because this data is only in one table. The reason for this query is because the data in the name fields are similar yet uniquely grouped by the way they were named. I hope i make sense.

select name, analysis from test_list_entry
where name like Left(@plant,3) + '%'

Assistance will appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Need a bit more. What is the difference between the two results. What does you data look like? If you open the dataset in the designer and test the query there, do you get the correct results. Also as you are doing a string compare, try creating a simple dataset with just SELECT QUOTENAME(@plant) as the query and add a textfield to the report to display the result. This is to make sure you don't have any whitespace around your parameter. Try LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@plant)), 3) if you have whitespace.

Comment: Hi Alan, I dont know why I had whitespace in parameter however when I applied the left and right trim I got back all my results. Thank You

Comment: Whitespace, the invisible software killer! Glad you got it sorted.